# Mouse/Touch events in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mouseevent

Is there a way to **get mouse and/or touch events on UI elements** using **Xamarin Forms**? So far I only found the TapGestureRecognizer class, but I want the user to be able to move UI elements (PanGestureRecognizer?) but I haven't been able to locate anything that could help me achieve that.

I am looking for a cross-platform solution if possible (hence the user of Xamarin Forms) but I am ok with creating a platform-specific component that integrates with Xamarin Forms (e.g., I already created a custom base page class to add an iOS-specific background gradient page).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you give MR Gestures a look. It's a Xamarin.Forms component that adds very robust support for gestures. It works on all Xamarin.Forms platforms. From the website:

> MR.Gestures adds Down, Up, Tapping, Tapped, DoupleTapped, LongPressing, LongPressed, Panning, Panned, Swiped, Pinching, Pinched, Rotating and Rotated events to each and every layout, cell and view and to the ContentPage. These events will be raised when the user performs the corresponding touch gesture on the element.

It is not free, but at €10 it's a bargain. The documentation is great and the library works exactly as advertised.